# Android Studio Setup Issue

Tags: android-studio

hello I am trying to install android studio, when I launch it the setup wizard appears with this language, how do I change it to English, I have tried finding answers , but have gotten none thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to format my pc and reinstall windows, in order to get it to work like it should. I don't know if it will be the same for everyone. But if it become necessary I would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Region settings for your OS? Control Panel > Region and Clock. There are Region Format and Language preference settings that you can adjust that may be off English.

If an adjustment is made, you may also need to restart your system for changes to take effect.